Reference request: construction of the Grassmann scheme in EGA I
I'm giving a talk on the construction of the Grassmann scheme soon, & I'm interested in looking at Grothendieck's presentation. Based on this question I am looking for EGA section 9.7.4, & given the comments on this question it's in the second edition of EGA I (that section doesn't exist in the copy I have been using). Can anyone help me with a copy of this edition? (With apologies to the stated wishes of the late Grothendieck.) I can't seem to find it anywhere.
I've read plenty of presentations of this construction, which I believe to be in the spirit of the EGA version, but given the context of my talk I'd like to read the source material, if possible. French or English is fine :-).
Thank you!

"libgen [dot] is" is your friend.

@MartinBrandenburg ahh great point i will check there, thanks

Problem solved with thanks to Martin Brandenburg --- specifically the 1971 Springer edition has the section I needed.
